# JQuery slider next and prev buttons only work when click spamming them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm making a custom jquery slider where you can browse through content sliders by using next and prev buttons (classes next and prev in the DOM). For some reason the results I am getting are quite random, only changing from slide to slide after spamming the prev button,  I console log the results so that you can see the visible index.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var sliders = $('.slider');
 
 var show_index = 0;
 
 $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
 console.log(show_index);
 console.log(sliders.length);
 
 
 $('.prev').click(function(){
  
  console.log('clicked prev');
  
  if(show_index == 0){
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider'); 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index-1).addClass('active_slider'); 
   console.log(show_index);
  }
  
  else{
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider'); 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index--).addClass('active_slider');
            console.log(show_index);   
  }
    });
 
 
 
 $('.next').click(function(){
  
  console.log('clicked next');
  
  if(show_index == sliders.length){
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider'); 
      $('.slider').eq(0).addClass('active_slider'); 
   console.log(show_index);
  }
  
  else{
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider'); 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index++).addClass('active_slider');
            console.log(show_index);   
  }
    });
 
 
});
```

```css
/*GRAN SLIDER START*/
.gran_slider_maincontainer{width:100%; height:100vh; display:flex; flex-direction:column; overflow:hidden;}
.gran_slider_big_container{width:100%; position:relative; height:90vh; overflow:hidden;}
.prev{cursor:pointer; position:absolute; left:20px; z-index:9999999999999999999999999999; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}
.next{cursor:pointer; position:absolute; right:20px; z-index:9999999999999999999999999999;  top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}
.gran_slider_big_navegation_container{width:auto; height:30px; display:flex; align-items:center; position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:50px; z-index:10000;}
.gran_slider_big_navegation_dot{width:15px; height:15px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4); margin:0px 3px; border-radius:50%;}
.gran_slider_big_item_container{display:none; width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay{width:100%; height:100%; z-index:3; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3); position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
.gran_slider_big_item_image{width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2; background-position:center; background-size:cover;}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_container{width:55%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:10px;}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_title{font-size:45px; color:white; font-weight:600; margin-bottom:30px; text-shadow:5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_description{font-size:30px; color:white; font-weight:600 margin-bottom:30px; text-shadow:5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);}
.gran_slider_small_container{width:100%; height:10vh; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));}
.active_slider{display:flex;}
/*GRAN SLIDER END*/

.from_right_to_bottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 120px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: from_right_to_bottom;
  animation-delay: 1500ms;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  z-index:9999;
  text-align:right;
}

@keyframes from_right_to_bottom {
 
  0% {top: -200px; opacity: 0;}

  100% {top: 250px; opacity: 1;}
  
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="gran_slider_maincontainer" style="">
    <div class="gran_slider_big_container" style=" ">
     <i class="prev fa fa-chevron-left" style=""></i>
  <i class="next fa fa-chevron-right" style=""></i>
  <!--
        <div class="gran_slider_big_navegation_container" style=" ">
         <a class="gran_slider_big_navegation_dot" href="" style=""></a>
      <a class="gran_slider_big_navegation_dot" href="" style=""></a>
      <a class="gran_slider_big_navegation_dot" href="" style=""></a>
     </div>
  -->
     <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
  <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:red;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
  <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:green;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gran_slider_small_container" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you increment your global variable `show_index`? On the `prev` and `next` click events you find the slide with minus or plus the `show_index` but you never do something like `show_index = show_index - 1;`. It will probably always be 0

Comment: I added font awesome link so prev and next buttons are visible for everyone

Comment: @zgood I do $('.slider').eq(show_index++).addClass('active_slider'); or $('.slider').eq(show_index--).addClass('active_slider'); inside te else statements of next and prev functions

Comment: That doesn't set the global variable...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your global variable (`show_index`) in your click events. Just doing `show_index++` doesn't set the value... you need to set the value with an equals (`=`) sign, like this `show_index = {some value};`

Your `prev` click event should look more like this:

```
$('.prev').click(function() {
        console.log('clicked prev');
        if (show_index == 0) {
            $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = (sliders.length - 1); // set your global variable
            $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            console.log(show_index);
        } else {   
            $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = show_index - 1;  // set your global variable
            $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            console.log(show_index);
        }
    });
```

And the `next` one like this:

```
$('.next').click(function() {    
        console.log('clicked next');    
        if (show_index == (sliders.length- 1)) {      
            $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = 0; //set global variable
            $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            console.log(show_index);
        } else {       
            $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
            show_index = show_index + 1; //set global variable
            $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            console.log(show_index);
        }
    });
```

```js
var show_index = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var sliders = $('.slider');
         
 $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
 console.log(show_index);
 console.log(sliders.length);
 
 
 $('.prev').click(function(){
  
  console.log('clicked prev');
  
  if(show_index == 0){
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
show_index = (sliders.length - 1);// set it here
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider'); 
   console.log(show_index);
  }
  
  else{
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
show_index = show_index - 1; // set it here 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            console.log(show_index);   
  }
    });
 
 
 
 $('.next').click(function(){
  
  console.log('clicked next');
  
  if(show_index == (sliders.length- 1)){
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
show_index = 0; // set it here
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider'); 
   console.log(show_index);
  }
  
  else{
   
   
   $('.slider').eq(show_index).removeClass('active_slider');
show_index = show_index + 1; // set it here 
      $('.slider').eq(show_index).addClass('active_slider');
            console.log(show_index);   
  }
    });
 
 
});
```

```css
/*GRAN SLIDER START*/
.gran_slider_maincontainer{width:100%; height:100vh; display:flex; flex-direction:column; overflow:hidden;}
.gran_slider_big_container{width:100%; position:relative; height:90vh; overflow:hidden;}
.prev{cursor:pointer; position:absolute; left:20px; z-index:9999999999999999999999999999; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}
.next{cursor:pointer; position:absolute; right:20px; z-index:9999999999999999999999999999;  top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); font-size:20px; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}
.gran_slider_big_navegation_container{width:auto; height:30px; display:flex; align-items:center; position:absolute; bottom:25px; right:50px; z-index:10000;}
.gran_slider_big_navegation_dot{width:15px; height:15px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4); margin:0px 3px; border-radius:50%;}
.gran_slider_big_item_container{display:none; width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay{width:100%; height:100%; z-index:3; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3); position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
.gran_slider_big_item_image{width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2; background-position:center; background-size:cover;}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_container{width:55%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; padding:10px;}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_title{font-size:45px; color:white; font-weight:600; margin-bottom:30px; text-shadow:5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);}
.gran_slider_big_item_texts_description{font-size:30px; color:white; font-weight:600 margin-bottom:30px; text-shadow:5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);}
.gran_slider_small_container{width:100%; height:10vh; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));}
.active_slider{display:flex;}
/*GRAN SLIDER END*/

.from_right_to_bottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 120px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: from_right_to_bottom;
  animation-delay: 1500ms;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  z-index:9999;
  text-align:right;
}

@keyframes from_right_to_bottom {
 
  0% {top: -200px; opacity: 0;}

  100% {top: 250px; opacity: 1;}
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="gran_slider_maincontainer" style="">
    <div class="gran_slider_big_container" style=" ">
     <i class="prev fa fa-chevron-left" style=""></i>
  <i class="next fa fa-chevron-right" style=""></i>
  <!--
        <div class="gran_slider_big_navegation_container" style=" ">
         <a class="gran_slider_big_navegation_dot" href="" style=""></a>
      <a class="gran_slider_big_navegation_dot" href="" style=""></a>
      <a class="gran_slider_big_navegation_dot" href="" style=""></a>
     </div>
  -->
     <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
  <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:red;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
  <div class="gran_slider_big_item_container slider" style="">
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_gradient_overlay" style=""></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_image move" style="background-color:green;"></div>
         <div class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_container from_right_to_bottom" style=" ">
       <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_title" style="">Titulo</span>
    <span class="gran_slider_big_item_texts_description" style="">Esta es una descripción que se mueve hacia la derecha, empezando por fuera de la derecha.</span>
   </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gran_slider_small_container" style=""></div>
</div>
```